# On Linux I cannot bind to wireguard network interface via IP, but can with interface name

Tags: linux, networking, ip, wireguard, network-interface

I have a WireGuard connection on my computer that I wish to only bind certain programs to. Programs that bind via the interface name (`wg0` in my case) bind correctly, but programs that bind via interface IP keep timing out on every connection. The most simple demonstration is via curl:

```
$ curl -m 10 --interface wg0 ip.me
xxx.xxx.177.89
```

```
$ curl -m 10 --interface 10.2.0.2 ip.me
curl: (28) Failed to connect to ip.me port 80 after 5002 ms: Connection timed out
```

Running `ifconfig` shows the following output for the interface:

```
wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1320
        inet 10.2.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.2.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 1917781  bytes 2607954812 (2.6 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 95781  bytes 10048520 (10.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 42115 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Since some programs can only bind via the interface IP rather than via an interface name, the fact that the connection fails when doing this is presenting a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, binding via IP address does not actually change *where* packets are sent. They're still sent following your routing table, and it most likely still has a default route through somewhere else – the packet still goes through eth0 no matter what source IP address it now has.

(On the other hand, binding via interface completely bypasses routing; with Ethernet interfaces it only works when the destination is on your own subnet. It only works here because WireGuard/Tun/PPP interfaces are not "layer2" interfaces, i.e. they don't use MAC addressing.)

To make this work properly with IPv4 you need to use *policy routing,* with multiple routing tables that are selected based on some condition.

1. If you're using wg-quick to set up the WireGuard connection, add `Table = 102` so that wg-quick would automatically add routes to that table.

   Otherwise, specify that setting wherever you're defining routes via WireGuard, e.g. if you're doing that manually through CLI, you would do:

   ```
   ip -4 route add default dev wg0 table 102
   ip -6 route add default dev wg0 table 102
   ```
2. Add a policy routing rule to select the new table:

   ```
   ip -4 rule add from 10.2.0.2 lookup 102
   ```

> Running `ifconfig` shows the following output for the interface:

`ifconfig` on Linux is not to be trusted. In the best case, it shows what `ip -s addr` would show, but it has never been updated for "new" (i.e. post-2003) OS interfaces and is still unable to show multiple IPv4 addresses per interface – among other things – making it a terrible choice for troubleshooting.